# Strange result when downloading a csv via writeStream

Tags: node.js, csv

I have a function on my nodejs server that downloads a CSV file from a link, and then once it's downloaded, it runs the parsing function.

The URL is of the following format:

`http://myprovider/grails/mgmt/downloadFile.dispatch?uid=12345&username=Lucas&password=Password`

```
function getItemCSVsingle(ItemLinkObject) {

    var ItemName=ItemLinkObject.nameLabel;
    var ItemURL=ItemLinkObject.url;

    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(ItemDownloadPath.concat(ItemName).concat('.csv'));
    writeStream.on('finish', function() {        
        loadItemCSV(ItemName);
    })
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: ItemURL,
    }).pipe(writeStream)
}
```

But then our data provider switched to links that require Basic Authentication.

So the new function looks like this - **and the URL that I'm constructing works with no problems if I copy and paste it into Chrome, so it's valid.** By works I mean it results in a CSV file download.

```
function getItemCSVwithAuth(ItemLinkObject) {

    var ItemName=ItemLinkObject.nameLabel;
    var ItemURL='https://'+username+':'password+'@'+ItemLinkObject.url;

    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(ItemDownloadPath.concat(ItemName).concat('.csv'));
    writeStream.on('finish', function() {    
        loadItemCSV(ItemName);
    })
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: ItemURL,    
    }).pipe(writeStream)
}
```

The problem is that when I execute this request on my node server, the resultant CSV file is very weird, only 440 bytes (instead of expected 2KB) and when I open it in sublime it looks like this:

```
1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0400 a594 dd6a dc30
1085 ef0b 7d07 3f80 6035 3fd2 48bd dba4
49ae 5296 26f4 dec4 4a10 ac63 70ec bc5c
2ffa 487d 858e b7a1 6c31 1595 8397 99c5    
307a f1a5 1608 0000
```

Comment: I would try postman to determine the source of the issue.

Comment: Or, you can just remove pipe, and add usual callback to see how content is received.

Comment: `1f8b` (first two bytes) indicate that the data is gzip-compressed, try setting `gzip : true` in the options passed to `request`

Comment: @robertklep that's very wired because same link when pasted in the chrome browser results in csv download (non compressed)

Comment: Chrome decompresses the data for you, `request` (by default) does not (AFAIK).

Comment: @robertklep `gzip : true` did the job - please post it as a separate answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two bytes of the response, `1f8b`, indicate that the response is gzip-compressed (which is common for HTTP responses, although usually, a client has to specifically tell the server that it supports such compression, which I don't think `request` does).

To enable decompression in `request`, enable the `gzip` option:

```
request({
  method : 'GET',
  uri    : ItemURL,   
  gzip   : true, 
}).pipe(writeStream)
```